# java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1 in Android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I tried to play a file in `ListView` with `mediaPlayer` class.

Like this:

```
public void initializeViews() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String fName = intent.getStringExtra("fileName");
    fileName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fileName);
    duration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songDuration);
    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    playBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.media_play);
    try {
        mediaPlayer = new android.media.MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fName);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    fileName.setText(fName.substring(fName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
    finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(mOnSeek);
    seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
    seekbar.setClickable(true);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    seekbar.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);
    durationHandler.postDelayed(updateSeekBarTime, 200);
}
```

I search on the internet, and the most question is check the path to file, but the `fName` got the full path to a file. But I don't know it shows exception:

`java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1`

All log when application occurs exception:

```
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at kr.co.composer.callrecord.media.AudioPlayer.initializeViews(AudioPlayer.java:56)
W/System.err:     at kr.co.composer.callrecord.media.AudioPlayer.onCreate(AudioPlayer.java:42)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/MediaPlayer: Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 0
E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
stop called in state 0
error (-38, 0)
stop called in state 0
error (-38, 0)
Error (-38,0)
Error (-38,0)
stop called in state 0
error (-38, 0)
Error (-38,0)
pause called in state 0
error (-38, 0)
```

Comment: Can you add more log?

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen I updated my log on question.

Answer (score 0):

Possible caused by reading permission. Fix by inserting the permission in `manifest` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I added permission. But this error is continues appear.